# Repository Pattern - Validating Object and Return Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

I'm working on a website, and just trying to get my head around the general structure. I have a database in the background that I'm accessing using the "Repository Pattern". I have the below code in my **UserRepository** class:

```
public bool IsValid(User user)
{
  if (_context.Users.Any(c => c.EmailAddress == user.EmailAddress))
  {
    Message = "Email address already in use";
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

And that is implemented here

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(User user)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var context = new Context("DatabaseContext");
    var userRepo = new UserRepository(context);

    if (userRepo.IsValid(user))
    {
      userRepo.Add(user);
      // return to different view
    }
    else
    {
      // display userRepo.Message on page
      return View(user);
    }
  }

  return View(user);
}
```

My problem is I don't think I'm going around the "message" bit correctly, but I can't find anything online to help me out (specifically around repository). I *think* I should be changing the return type of **IsValid** to something like a result (as I've seen with dialog boxes), but again, I'm not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Right now, you have one validation criteria, so a bool would make sense. If things get much more complicated, consider returning the message (a string) on an error and then check if it is null (on a success). Or if needed you could go as far as what the ModelState does in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is exactly like you have suggested - *change the return type of `IsValid`*.

In the past I have had similar validation methods in my "business layer" that return a collection of `ValidationResult`, where each returned record accounts for a validation error within the model and an empty collection would be interpreted as a valid model.

For example:

```
public class ValidationResult
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidator<T>
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IsValid(T model);
}

//...in your implementation
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IsValid(User user)
{
    //Return a new ValidationResult per validation error
    if (_context.Users.Any(c => c.EmailAddress == user.EmailAddress))
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult
        {
            Message = "Email address already in use",
            FieldName = nameof(user.EmailAddress)
        };
    }
}
```

This could then be interpreted by your presentation layer to feedback to the user.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not only have you given me a nice solution, but you've actually helped me understand how "yield return" works.

Comment: @oyyou please check my answer. May be that will help you to understand more.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what you mentioned in question. Returning custom class will be better approach IMO.

```
public ValidationResult IsValid(User user)
{
  ValidationResult validationResult = new ValidationResult(true, "");
  if (_context.Users.Any(c => c.EmailAddress == user.EmailAddress))
  {
    validationResult.Status = false;
    validationResult.Message = "Email address already in use";
    return validationResult;
  }

  return validationResult;
}
```

This way, `Status` and `Message` give you all info needed. Check the status first. If it is false, check message for exact details.

Comment: I like this. It's easy to understand, and implement. I'm going to Mark Oliver's as the answer as it'll give-way for expanding; but this is still valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution provided by above user is good but I don't think you are doing this in right way. This kind of validating email address solution has some cons.

Suppose If email is available(not valid because this is not validity) then you have to return view with error.And what if all input email address is available then the end user will get this error multiple time but the whole view will be rendered in every request and this is not good practice.Always try to use remote validation in this kind of scenario.

Use `Remoteattribute` on your model properties (email) and try to return availability message dynamically in view through `JsonResult`.I am giving you this demo example feel free to implement in your code.

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public JsonResult IsEmailAvailable(string emailAddress)
{
    if (!_context.Users.Any(c => c.EmailAddress == emailAddress))
    {
         return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json("Email address already taken" , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The `OutputCacheAttribute` attribute is required in order to prevent ASP.NET MVC from caching the results of the validation methods.

And decorate your model Email property like this:

```
//inside you model.
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsEmailAvailable", "YourControllerName")]
    [RegularExpression(@"Your email address validation regex here", ErrorMessage = "Email address is not valid .")]
    [Editable(true)]
    public string Email{ get; set; }
```

And add this snippet in the Web.config file to allow the use of the Remote attribute:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

And remove following code from `register` action method.

```
if (userRepo.IsValid(user))
    {
      userRepo.Add(user); //write this only inside code cause you will always get valid email now.
      // return to different view
    }
    else
    {
      // display userRepo.Message on page
      return View(user);
    }
```

I hope this will work. For more information please read this article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx

Comment: client-side validation is a good *addition*.  You still need server validation for malicious/erroneous requests.

Comment: This is providing server side validation. where i mentioned client side validation.@Oliver

Comment: There is almost always some validation that is based on business rules, for example an email address may not be duplicated between 2 users.  This is why a business level validation method is a good option in addition to client/presentation level validation.

Comment: yeah i know that's so this answer is also doing the same thing. Since I cannot explain whole thing here this is just solution. Check for remote validation in MVC.This will show you how this is working https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx